# Density of a given distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

Given the distirbution function as follows:

$F(x) = x^2$ for $ 0 \leq x < \frac{1}{2}$, $F(x) = x$ for $\frac{1}{2} \leq x < 1$, $F(x) = 1$ for $x > 1$ and $F(x) = 0$ for $x<0$.

Is it true that the density then equals $f(x) = 2x$ for $0 \leq x < \frac{1}{2}$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $ \frac{1}{2} < x <1$ and $0$ else?

Because the integral doesn't sum up to 1, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx=\frac{3}{4} \neq 1$, or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
F_X(x)=
\begin{cases}
0&\text{ if }& x<0\\
x^2&\text{ if }& 0\le x\le \frac12\\
x&\text{ if }&\frac12<x\le 1\\ 
1&\text{ if }& x>1
\end{cases}$$

The graph of this cdf looks like this

[image]

$F$ does have a discontinuity at $\frac12$. The limit is $\frac14$ from the left and it is $\frac12$ from the right.  The point is that there is a jump of $\frac14$ at $\frac12$.

So, there is no density because there is a single point $\left(\frac12\right)$ whose probability is $\frac14$.

The distribution consists of an absolute continuous part, the density mentioned by the OP (its integral is $\frac34$) and an atom. The total probabilty is $1$.

Comment: So it's basically a mixed r.v. If I want to compute the expectation then, the formula should be: $EX = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} x\cdot 2x dx + \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1} x dx + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \ldots = \frac{7}{12}$ right?

Comment: @C.G. Seems to be right. The point is that $\frac12$ is in with weight $\frac14$.